# Write javascript for confirm delete in gridview rowdeleting event

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, delete-row

I am deleting a row from gridview for which i have used gridview's default delete command field. On clicking, the gridview row deleting command gets fired and the selected row gets deleted. All good till now.

But before the row gets deleted, i need to set confirmation message to user. On clicking of OK button the row should get deleted else not (on click of cancel button).

I have the code as;

```
return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');
```

But this works fine if there is a linkbutton (instead of command field) as i could easily write on OnClick event of linkbutton and could add the attributes in Gridview RowDataBound event.

How the same would work for command's field delete button? Please guide!

Thanks!

Comment: would you prefer jquery or are you looking for something in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article explains how to do exactly what you need:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Gridview_Delete_confirmLS.aspx

And here is the code you need to do it:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // loop all data rows
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
           // check all cells in one row
           foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
           {
                // Must use LinkButton here instead of ImageButton
                // if you are having Links (not images) as the command button.
                ImageButton button = control as ImageButton;

                if (button != null && button.CommandName == "Delete")
                    // Add delete confirmation
                    button.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is accepted answer, it doesn't work. It displays correctly the confirmation dialog, but it when I click OK, it doesn't generate postback event. Your code is different from the code on that codeproject page - and that one works. Please update your code.

Comment: Have you considered that there may be an issue with your implementation of the code? Pretty straight-forward stuff here.

Comment: Something is wrong somewhere, of course possibly in my code. But I really need to rewrite that "return confirm('...');" to "if(!confirm('...')) return false;" to work in my Firefox. It effectively means "if true, don't return". Other variants don't work for me. Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is code which you can use....

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataControlField dcf in GridView1.Columns)
        {

            if (dcf.ToString() == "CommandField")
            {
                if (((CommandField)dcf).ShowDeleteButton == true)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[GridView1.Columns.IndexOf(dcf)].Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no,cannot use linkbutton or template field. I have to use commandfield delete button only

Comment: Will the code work, if i have written the code to delete the gridview row in rowdeleting event?

Comment: yes, it should work, the code in my answer is show confirm on command field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
            {
                // Choose between Button, ImageButton and LinkButton.
                // as my ButtonType="Button". 
                Button button = control as Button;
                if (button != null && button.CommandName == "Delete")
                {
                    string script = "if(confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) __doPostBack('{0}','{1}${2}'); else return false;";
                    string clickEvent = String.Format(
                        script,
                        GridView1.ClientID,
                        button.CommandName,
                        button.CommandArgument);
                    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", clickEvent);                                 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Much more dirty than I originally anticipated. Better to use a `asp:TemplateField` :)

Please note that my `ButtonType="Button"`

Comment: Will the code if i am writing code to delete the row in Gridview_rowdeleting event?